# Hybris Init only init the staged catalog

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I created a new extension with a addonproject and initialdata project. Sadly all my impexes are only updating the "Staged" Catalog when initializing.

I tried to change the IntialDataSystemSetup.java to explicitly import the impexes but they still only show up in the staged catalog. Is there a conflict with the default data from the powertoolsstore?

Comment: Impex is indeed to change the stage version. During Initializing, internally sync job runs to sync your catalog. You might get the error during sync phase. Do catalog synchronization from HMC/BackOffice.

Comment: If you import data in "Online" but not in "Staged", the data get probably erased when the synchronization occurs from "Staged" to "Online".

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In the new extension was this missing:
In the class: InitialDataSystemSetup.java

```
getCoreDataImportService().synchronizeContentCatalog(this, context, "powertools", true);
```

Thank you for your help